# Angular directive is only loading part of jQuery plugin (pickadate) dynamically

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, pickadate

I have an ng-repeat rendering a directive, as the ng-repeat will be of unknown length I'm attempting to dynamically load a jquery plugin on click, via a directive.

I believe I'm quite close, however, only part of the plugin loads, and unfortunately no errors are given. For those familiar with the [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) plugin, the classes are being rendered on the input element, however the elements that it appends dynamically are not being rendered on click.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="calendar" add-calendar>Click to add calendar</div>
```

**Angular Directive 1**

```
agentApp.directive('addCalendar', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            template = '<input type="text" jq-date-picker-range />';

            element.bind('click', function() {
                angular.element(this).after($compile(template)(scope));
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Angular Directive 2**

```
agentApp.directive('jqDatePickerRange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          angular.element(element).pickadate();
        }
    };
});
```

**Output**

```
<input type="text" jq-date-picker-range class="ng-scope picker__input picker__input--active" readonly="" id="P780839543" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="P780839543_root">
```

As you can see, the classes are being written, but the calendar div elements which are rendered thereafter are not doing so.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was a rendering one. Effectively, I assume the thread responsible for rendering is busy when I make the initial call, so the ability of the plugin to add classes to existing DOM elements is available, however adding new elements to the DOM is not. I assume there's a better way than this solution - and I'd love to hear it. But for now, wrapping the call in a $timeout function does the trick.

```
agentApp.directive('jqDatePickerRange', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          $timeout(function() {
            angular.element(element).pickadate();
          }, 0);

        }
    };
}]);
```